# Three phase solid state control switch

Tags: power-electronics, solid-state-relay

I want to get three phase input to an output when all the phases are available.

If I have lines, L1, L2, L3  and like to have one of the output with any one of those phases.

**If any of the phase is over or under voltage, output should be off, otherwise output should be on.**

I'm trying to use this to control three phase solid state switch. Output can be less than 1 Amperes.

L1, L2, L3 -- Voltage ranges from 170 to 250 to Neutral.

What is the best component I need to look for in the market to solve this problem? Better to have a solid state instead of anything mechanical relays.

If there are any companies offering a readymade device to this problem, please share it as well.

Thanks for the help.

**Update:**

Here are the exact components I'm trying to use.

http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/ha-series-ha48-ac-panel-mount.pdf

ha48 needs AC as a control signal to turn and off. I have one for each phase, all connected to a single control input.

Need a device to a single control output that takes L1,L2 and L3 as three inputs checks for under/over voltage and gives the control output.

Comment: SCRs/thyristors. Note the way they must turn off.

Comment: If any of the L1, L2, L3 or over / under with a configured voltage they must turn off.

Comment: You do not understand my comment which you would not if you do no know how they work. Just go read about how they work.

Comment: There is a device called a phase monitoring relay, several companies make them and they are reasonably priced. I believe they will do what you want.

Comment: @Gil Thanks for the comment. That looks good one. Not seeing anything with solid state phase monitoring relay. Anything like that exist ?

Comment: Google: three phase monitoring relay

Comment: Yes I believe Eaton and Square D offer them for sale, there are more but none come to mind at the present time. I have used them many times over the years. You can google for phase monitor.